# How to scrape a webpage that changes content from <select> tag

Tags: python, web-scraping

I want to scrape a webpage that changes its content via a `<select`> tag. When I select a different option, the content of the page dynamically changes. I want to know if there is a way that I can change the option from a python script so I can get the content from all different pages of all different options in `<select>` tag.

Comment: Just interacting with `select` element doesn't change the document. There must be some Javascript involved. Find out, what happens and add your results to your question.

Comment: What browser are you using? I know google chrome at least can change the html it is viewing. With that, you could go in there and change the <select> tag.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use some library like urllib to do the scraping. You already know the website's content changes dynamically.  I also assume that the dynamic content uses server-side interaction. This means, using javascript (ajax) the browser requests new data from the server, based on the value from the selection).

If so, then you could try to emulate the ajax call to the server in your web scraping library.

1. First, using a browser debugging tool find out the url to the server that is being invoked.
2. Split the parameters parts in the ajax call
3. Perform the same call to lookup the options in the select tag.

Answer (score 0):

As @Tichodroma said, when the select is changed, either:

1. Some content previously hidden on the page is made visible, or:
2. An ajax call is made to retrieve some additional content and add it to the DOM

In both cases, JavaScript is involved. Have a look at it, and depending on what is happening (case #1 or #2), you should:

1. Scrape the whole page, since all the content you want is already in it, or:
2. Make several calls to the file usually called using ajax to retrieve the content you want for each value of the `<select>`

Comment: the tag has an onchange event ="this.submit.form()", but i cant find the js page so i can find out what this function does. any idea?

Comment: To look for the first scenario, just hit ctrl+f when looking at the source of the page and search for the content that appears when you `<select>` an option.
If you don't find anything that way, then do as suggested by @hans-then: fire up your console (ctrl+shift+i on Chrome), switch to the Network tab, and then change the `<select>` value. If an ajax call is made, you'll see a new line appearing with the request uri, the method used, its parameters...